# Пролистываемый по вертикали Layout на Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Необходимо сделать layout на Android, который бы можно было пролистывать по вертикали!
То есть, беру layout и распологаю на нем управляющие элементы.

Как дальше на нем их располагать, когда закончился экран, по вертикали вниз?

Делаю так:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="758dp" >


    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: в ответе предложили правильный вариант, и не стоит задавать ширину и высоту числами, я так понимаю вы исходили из размеров какого-то экрана.

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
можно и так!
Само главное что не работает! С чем это может быть связано?
android:layout_height="758dp" 
а это нужно ставить числом! Как по другому то?

Comment: зачем вам высота именно такая?
попробуйте match_parent ;)

Comment: Нет я ее делал и врап контент и матч парент не работает и все! Может у меня с эклипсом что? Я вот сейчас хочу его заново установить

Answer (score 3):

Решение: использовать **ScrollView**

```
<ScrollView
     layoutWidth="match_parent"
     layoutHeight="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
         layoutWidth="match_parent"
         layoutHeight="wrap_content">
    .....
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Да я так и делаю! Но почему то не срабатывает!

Comment: @vanyamelikov а вы попробуйте ориентацию у LinearLayout задать вертикальную :)